# Reverse sort of Numpy array with NaN values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `numpy` array with some `NaN` values:

```
>>> a
array([  1.,  -1.,   nan,  0.,  nan], dtype=float32)
```

I can sort it in ascending or 'descending' order:

```
>>> numpy.sort(a)
array([ -1.,   0.,   1.,  nan,  nan], dtype=float32)
>>> numpy.sort(a)[::-1]
array([ nan,  nan,   1.,   0.,  -1.], dtype=float32)
```

However, what I want is descending order with `NaN` values at the end, like this:

```
>>> numpy.genuine_reverse_sort(a)
array([ 1.,   0.,   -1.,  nan,  nan], dtype=float32)
```

How could this be accomplished? I suspect that there is no special method for this.

Comment: Why not just count NaN's, remove them, sort, then concatenate NaN's at the end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're probably right -- there is no built in special method to do this. But you could do it in two steps as follows by rolling your NaNs into the place you want them:

```
a = np.array([  1.,  -1.,   np.nan,  0.,  np.nan], dtype=np.float32)
sa = np.sort(a)[::-1]
np.roll(sa,-np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(a)))

array([  1.,   0.,  -1.,  nan,  nan], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 6):

What about negating the values twice:

```
>>> a = np.array([2., -1., nan,  0., nan])
>>> np.sort(a)
array([ -1.,   0.,   2.,  nan,  nan])
>>> -np.sort(-a)
array([  2.,   0.,  -1.,  nan,  nan])
```

Comment: Thanks! This is useful for multi-dimensional arrays and when I'm sorting in a single axis. I'm not sure if the other methods mentioned here work. I was thinking of replacing `nan`s with `-1`, sort and replace `-1` with `nan`s. (All elements in my array are non-negative). But yours is better. Solves it in a single step, instead of 3.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.argpartition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) to sort only the `non-NaNs`, like so -

```
a[np.argpartition(-a, np.arange((~np.isnan(a)).sum()) )]
```

Sample run -

```
In [253]: a
Out[253]: array([  1.,  -1.,  nan,   0.,  nan,   2.,   4.,  -2., -10.,  nan])

In [254]: a[np.argpartition(-a, np.arange((~np.isnan(a)).sum()) )]
Out[254]: array([  4.,   2.,   1.,   0.,  -1.,  -2., -10.,  nan,  nan,  nan])
```

Comment: Works, but it adds no value over `a[np.argsort(-a)]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
>>> np.concatenate((np.sort(a[~np.isnan(a)])[::-1], [np.nan] * np.isnan(a).sum()))
array([ 1.,   0.,   -1.,  nan,  nan])
```

With this fragment you reverse sort the numerical entries of the input array, and then you concatenate with the appropriate number of `nan` values.